# React Native stack navigator Some files doesn't exist error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I am new to React Native. Recently I try to figure out stack navigator. I runned these comments on terminal.

npm install @react-navigation/native
npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context
npm install @react-navigation/stack
npm install react-native-gesture-handler

here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, AppState } from "react-native";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function ScreenA(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text> Screen A</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Screen_A"
          component={ScreenA}
        />    
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And I get this error message:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWKEH.png)

While trying to resolve module `@react-navigation/elements` from file `/Users/ogulcanozen/food/node_modules/@react-navigation/stack/src/views/Header/Header.tsx`, the package `/Users/ogulcanozen/food/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/ogulcanozen/food/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/src/index.tsx`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

- /Users/ogulcanozen/food/node_modules/@react-navigation/elements/src/index.tsx(.native|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try reseting the Metro cache and restarting?

Comment: Are you using expo?

Comment: Have you tried installing `@react-navigation/elements` as well?